# Is there any way to sum duplicate rows when deleting duplicates using CTE?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

I have a table that contains duplicated `ItemId`. I am using `CTE` to remove the duplicate records and keep only single record for each item. I am able to successfully achieve this milestone using following Query:

```
Create procedure sp_SumSameItems
as
begin
    with cte as (select a.Id,a.ItemId,Qty, QtyPrice, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by ItemId ORDER BY Id) AS rn from tblTest a)
    delete x from tblTest x Join cte On x.Id = cte.Id where cte.rn > 1
end
```

The actual problem is I want to `Sum` the `Qty` and `QtyPrice` before deleting duplicate records. Where should I add `Sum` function ?

Problem Illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `update` with `delete` statement, you need to `update` before :

```
update t
     set t.qty = (select sum(t1.qty) from table t1 where t1.itemid = t.itemid);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

A CTE is valid for only one statement, so you will need to either run the cte twice, once summing and then deleting or you could put the result of CTE in a temp table and then use the temp table to sum and then delete records in the original table.

Comment: For your current solution just run an update first as shown by Yogesh Sharma's answer.

Answer (score 0):

At first level, you have to update Qty and QtyPrice after that remove duplicate records.

Given Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_sumsameitems 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      WITH cte1 
           AS (SELECT a.id, 
                      a.itemid, 
                      Sum(qty)     Qty, 
                      Sum(qtyprice)QtyPrice, 
               FROM   tbltest a 
               GROUP  BY a.id) 
      UPDATE x 
      SET    x.qty = c.qty, 
             x.qtyprice = c.qtyprice 
      FROM   tbltest x 
             JOIN cte1 c 
               ON x.id = cte.id 

      WITH cte 
           AS (SELECT a.id, 
                      a.itemid, 
                      qty, 
                      qtyprice, 
                      Row_number() 
                        OVER( 
                          partition BY itemid 
                          ORDER BY id) AS rn 
               FROM   tbltest a) 
      DELETE x 
      FROM   tbltest x 
             JOIN cte 
               ON x.id = cte.id 
      WHERE  cte.rn > 1 
  END
```